# A question about irreducible characters of defect one

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, characters

Let $G$ be a finite group and $p$ a prime divisor of $|G|$. Also let $\mathrm{Irr}(G)$ and $\mathrm{IBr}(G)$ denote the set of irreducible complex characters and irreducible $p$-Brauer characters of $G$, respectively. It is well known that if $\chi \in \mathrm{Irr}(G)$, then the restriction of $\chi$ to $p$-regular elements of $G$ is a $p$-Brauer character, which is denoted by $\chi^0$. Therefore, we have $\chi^0=\Sigma_{\phi \in\mathrm{IBr}(G)}{d_{\chi\phi}~\phi}$. The integers $d_{\chi\phi}$ are called decomposition numbers.
Now assume that $\chi \in \mathrm{Irr}(G)$ is of defect one, that is $\chi(1)_p=\frac{|G|_p}{p}$. (For a natural number $n$, $n_p$ denotes the $p$-part of $n$ for the prime divisor $p$ of $n$). I heard in a recent talk that in this case, all the decomposition numbers $d_{\chi\phi}$ are less than or equal to $1$, and $\chi^0$ has at most $p-1$ irreducible constituents. I found that the first part of the assertion has been proved by  Brauer. But still I don't see why the number of irreducible constituents of $\chi^0$ don't exceed $p$ in this case?
 I would be grateful if you could explain it and enlighten my mind. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think no one can answer your question briefly because one of the deepest theorem (Brauer's theorem of blocks of defect one, or Dade's theorem of blocks with cyclic defect groups) of the modular representation theory of finite groups is probably needed. See, for instance, Section 68 of Dornhoff (1972).